# Clear checkboxes if "Anywhere" option is checked

Tags: angular, checkbox

I would like to uncheck all the checkboxes apart from the option "Anywhere in the world" if I choose the option "Anywhere in the world" using Angular. I have looked at a lot of ways to do so but none of it fits my solution. What would be the easiest way to do so?

```
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
       <label for="targetMarket" style="font-size: 17px">
           What is/are your current/proposed target market(s)?
       </label>
       <div class="form-check">
           <label class="checkbox-inline">
               <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="southAsia" value="1" #southAsiaChk
                   (change)="onCheckArray($event, Form.value.targetMarket)">
                        South Asia
           </label>
       </div>
       <div class="form-check">
           <label class="checkbox-inline">
               <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="northAsia" value="2" #northAsiaChk
                   (change)="onCheckArray($event, Form.value.targetMarket)">
                        North Asia
           </label>
       </div>
       <div class="form-check">
           <label class="checkbox-inline">
               <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="oceania" value="3" #oceaniaChk
                   (change)="onCheckArray($event, Form.value.targetMarket)">
                        Australia/New Zealand
           </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="anywhere" class="checkbox" name="anywhere" value="9" #anywhereChk
                    (change)="onCheckArray($event, Form.value.targetMarket)" (click)="uncheckRegions()">
                        Anywhere in the world
            </label>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sorts of the way:

First one is adding a `state` and using `[(ngModel)]` to update the checkbox checked state.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-base-i41w6c?file=src/app/app.component.ts) (I'm not making a new one but using one of the existing demos which I improved)

Code:

`this.data.forEach(x => { x.state = ev.target.checked; });`

note that `this.data` is an array which contains state bind to `[(ngModel)]` `[(ngModel)]="content.state"` in the example.

The second one is manually detecting:

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gznwcb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Both is almost the same, which is check or uncheck everything. The difference is I add a condition to let anywhere to be excluded from unchecking. Which you could easily implement too if you used the first way.

Code:

```
const input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
Array.from(input).forEach(res => {
  if (res.type == 'checkbox') {
    if (res.attributes[2].value != 'anywhere') {
      res.checked = false;
    }
  }
})
```

---

Update:

To prevent unchecking when anywhere is unticked you could use [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to get anywhere checked state:
`@ViewChild('anywhereChk') anywhere;`

then add an additional condition:

```
if (res.attributes[2].value != 'anywhere' && this.anywhere.nativeElement.checked==true) {
    res.checked = false;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpc6ox?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: thank you! it worked well. however, if I uncheck the "anywhere" option, it shouldnt affect anything but instead it unchecks everything as well. How can I solve that?

Comment: If you know anywhere would be the last input you could do: `input[input.length-1].checked==true` see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkx6ky?file=src/app/app.component.ts. Or you could find anywhere input and check it's state.

Comment: @mhfour See update for everything being unaffected on anywhere untick

Comment: thanks alot! it works now. one question: what is the meaning of `res.attributes[2].value`? why is there a 2 in the brackets?

Comment: `input` is a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) where each collection has [`attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) and `[2]` refer to second index of `input.attributes`. You can use `console.log(res)` to check live, for more detail you can refer documentation which I linked.